# Having a problem with getting 2 properties in one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

Alright so basically I have this object called user utils and I'm supposed to add an object to it called search which has two properties called byName and byCountry. If I run the first one while having the second one commented it works properly but when I try to run the first one without having the second one commented it says "TypeError: userUtils.search.byName is not a function". If I run the second one it runs properly even if the first one isn't commented.

```
userUtils.search = {
  byName: function(name, fuzzy) {
    let matchedNames;
    matchedNames = users.filter(function(element) {
      if (fuzzy) {
        return (
          element.name.first.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase()) ||
          element.name.last.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase())
        );
      }
      return element.name.first.startsWith(name) || element.name.last.startsWith(name);
    });
    return matchedNames;
  }
};
userUtils.search = {
  byCountry: function(...args) {
    let argArray = args;
    let matchedCountries = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        if (argArray[i] === users[j].address.country) {
          matchedCountries[count] = users[j];
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    return matchedCountries;
  }
};
```

Comment: Use `userUtils.search.byCountry = function(...args) {..}` because by using `userUtils.search = ..` you are overriding the previous value of `userUtils.search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring the definition of 'userUtils.search' each time. My recommendation to you would be to declare what 'userUtils.search' is first, and then start with its children.

```
userUtils.search = {};

userUtils.search.byName = function(name, fuzzy) {
    let matchedNames;

    matchedNames = users.filter(function(element) {
        if (fuzzy) {
            return (
                element.name.first.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase())
                    || element.name.last.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase())
            );
        }
        return element.name.first.startsWith(name) || element.name.last.startsWith(name);
    });

    return matchedNames;
};

userUtils.search.byCountry = function(args) {
    let argArray = args,
        matchedCountries = [],
        count = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
            if (argArray[i] === users[j].address.country) {
                matchedCountries[count] = users[j];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedCountries;
};
```

Speaking of such though, have you thought of using an Array.push() instead of your 'count' in the 'byCountry' function?

Example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        if (argArray[i] === users[j].address.country) {
            matchedCountries.push( users[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were just overwriting what the value of userUtils.search was each time.  You want to define the properties on the "search" object not it.

```js
var userUtils = userUtils || {};
userUtils.search = {
  byName: function(name, fuzzy) {
    let matchedNames;
    matchedNames = users.filter(function(element) {
      if (fuzzy) {
        return (
          element.name.first.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase()) ||
          element.name.last.toUpperCase().startsWith(name.toUpperCase())
        );
      }
      return element.name.first.startsWith(name) || element.name.last.startsWith(name);
    });
    return matchedNames;
  },
  byCountry: function(...args) {
    let argArray = args;
    let matchedCountries = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        if (argArray[i] === users[j].address.country) {
          matchedCountries[count] = users[j];
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    return matchedCountries;
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(userUtils.search))
```